# Loading image as resource returning null

Tags: java, eclipse, image, loading, embedded-resource

I have a folder to all my images, being /res/  to access these images i want to use my class's resource folder. 
so i use

```
    getClass().getResource("/res/image.png");
```

I have also tried

```
    getClass().getResourceLoader("/res/image.png");
```

i have also tried the same thing without the / in front of res.

to check the class path I did a Sytem.out.println

```
    System.out.println(this.getClass().getResource(""));
```

and it returned the path to my bin folder

when ever I try to get an Image from my /res folder it always returns null.
Within eclipse the res folder is assigned selected as an class folder.

how can i fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In eclipse, the contents of a folder declared as a source folder are put at the root of the classpath. In other words

```
/res // could be called anything 
    /image.png
```

will appear in

```
/ (classpath root)
    /image.png
```

so you can access it as

```
getClass().getResource("/image.png");
```

Alternatively, put it under

```
/res
    /res
        /image.png
```

if you want to keep it as is.

Comment: @opiop65 That depends on where the class returned by `getClass()` is.

Comment: @opiop65  If I had a dollar for every resource loading problem where adding a leading `/` *solved the problem,* I could afford to go on a nice holiday.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Really? I rarely ever have to add one! I wonder what I'm doing differently...

Comment: @opiop65 You must be accessing the resource relative to the class (correctly).  By adding the leading `/` we can use the exact same `String` for loading the resource from *any* class, irrespective of the package of that class.